# Calculate mean with known variance, reject rate and specification

Tags: poisson-distribution, means

I am trying to understand a quiz question and I'm unsure of which distribution is involved and how to go about working this out.

The question reads..
[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ3VW.png)

I know that the answer is 245 (as a result of guessing through the multiple choice option), but I don't know how to work this out. I assumed it is a poisson distribution question but I'm unsure.

Answer (score 0):

The mean breaking strength cannot possibly be less than the specification minimum of 255 for the given failure rate.

I don't know why you assumed a Poisson distribution, but if we assume that it's normally distributed (which is usually a good default assumption in the absence of specific information), then I get a mean of 265.3 using Excel's NORMDIST in conjunction with GoalSeek.

In general, regardless of the actual distribution, the mean will be such that

$$
\int_{-\infty}^x p({\bf v},\xi)\text d\xi-r_f=0
$$

where ${\bf v}$ is the vector of distribution parameters that are related to the mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, $x$ is the specification minimum (255 in the example) and $r_f$ is the reject rate (0.0197 in the example). Note that depending on the functional form of the cumulative distribution function, you may or may not need an iterative procedure to estimate $\mu$.

Comment: alright, I want to say that I'm a complete rookie on discrete distributions but the reason why I assumed a Poisson distribution was because Poisson events occur at a known mean rate and I was trying to work this out with the equation: λ = np although I couldn't work out what n is if I don't directly know p (the number of times the event occurs) I will try and work it out for 2 or more and see what I get

Comment: Try using an exponential distribution for which the CDF is

$$
D(x)=1-e^{\frac{x-x_0}{\mu_*}}
$$

where $\mu_*$ is the mean of the distribution of $x-x_0$ and which  equals the standard deviation (5 in this example). Setting $D(x)$ to equal the reject rate, you can calculate the offset $x_0$ and hence the actual mean.

Comment: Thank you for helping, but I do not have enough knowledge to understand these formulas as of now.  I have never used them before and I thought the original question was relating to something else. I am only aware of basic probability, binomial and poisson distributions

Comment: Should be $e^-(\frac{x-x_0}{\mu})$ in my comment above

Comment: In that case, I would recommend
https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-05-introduction-to-probability-and-statistics-spring-2014/